# No. 1, 2, 3 is right or Nos. 1, 2, 3

Tags: grammatical-number

I cannot decide whether to add -s after words like "No.", "Fig." etc. For example, in my paper, usually I need to express:

"Fig. 1, 2 and 3 are illustrations of xxx", "This figure shows the results of frame No. 1, 2, 3 in our video"...

As you can see, there are multiple numbers after the words like "Fig.", "No.". In my option, words like "Fig." or "No." never have plural. But someone said they have. I have confused. Which one is correct?

Comment: Surely you should always write them out in full, a situation under which the previous quandary evaporates.

Comment: @tchrist. Thanks for the advice. While I do need to use the abbreviations of words like Figure, Table, Number, Equation, etc. When I use the abbreviations like Fig. Tab. No. Eq., do I need to add -s if they are followed by multiple objects?

Comment: I cannot see where you would have to use abbreviations except perhaps as captions.  Most of those look poor and make things hard to read.  I’ve read thousands of highly technical refereed research papers, and while things like *Fig.* are common there, as in *(see Fig. 23)*, when speaking of several of them, it should be in Figures 1, 4, and 7–9.

Answer (score 2):

The abbreviations *nos.* and *figs.* are the correct plural forms, and are preferred.

The *Chicago Manual of Style* states the following rule:

> For most abbreviations, add *s* or *es* for plural forms, unless otherwise stated.

Nevertheless, most scholarly Latin abbreviations have irregular plurals usually formed by doubling a letter, such as *pp.* as plural of *p.* (page) and *qq.v.* as plural of *q.v.* (*quod vide*). Consequently, if you are using any additional abbreviations, look for proper pluralization.

(NB: The CMOS shows *no.* and *fig.* with an initial *minuscule* letter. Consult your preferred style guide to determine correct capitalization.)